Is it possible to change the Data source of a grafana visualization with a dashboard variable?
So my questions are:
Is there a way to dynamically change the Data source of a grafana visualization using a dashboard variable (we can get variables from Data sources)?
Or is there another approach that doesn't require the duplication of the dashboard with visualizations pointing to a different Data source?
Any help appreciated.


Yes
